# Which way of using variables is more efficient in terms of speed, cpu, memory, etc in python?

Tags: python, variables

Assume we have a function which wants to operate some actions on attribute z of objA. objA is a property of objB and objB is a property of objC etc... which of these two approaches is faster ? Is there any difference?

Approach 1: Using `objC.objB.objA.z`for every statement in the function.

Approach 2: Assigning a local variable like x in function as:

```
x=objC.objB.objA.z
```

then operate on x, then assign the output to the preferable variable.

I know Approach 2 makes it easier in terms of writing the actual code but doesn't defining a new variable cost more memory? Which approach is more pythonic and is there any other (better) way to do things other than aforementioned approaches?

Comment: There is a small cost in the `.` lookups, but it's probably trivial compared to any actual gruntwork in the code.  Don't worry about such things, just write clear and readable code and then profile it later if-and-only-if optimisation is needed.

Comment: Note, though, that the `.` lookups could be running property code, which could make them substantially slower.

Comment: So . lookups are the delaying points. About the delay being quantum or mega, it doesn't make any difference for me as I want to call variables like this like 10e6 times in few seconds! so every small approach to efficiency has a great reflect on the whole project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 2 will in general be quicker, although it may not be a noticeable difference unless it's in a tight loop.

Every time you do `a.b.c.d`, Python has to look up the values of those attributes, even if they don't change in between uses.  If you create a variable `x` for that value once, then Python only has to look up the attributes once, saving time.

Doing `x = a.b.c.d` does *not* create a new object, so it doesn't use any memory.  `x` will be a reference to the same object that `a.b.c.d` pointed to.  However, because of this, you do need to be careful.  Any operations that mutate `x` will affect the original object.  For instance, if `a.b.c.d` is a list, and you do `x = a.b.c.d`, then `x.append(1)` will alter the value of the original `a.b.c.d` object.  If this is what you want, great.  If not, be sure to explicitly copy the value.

Comment: Very well put. Actually the last statement about x.append was absolutely a wise notice I should keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd one is more pythonic and it will also be faster if you are reusing `objC.objB.objA.z` many times because it avoids having to do those 4 lookups each time. It isn't costly to bind this value to `x`, Python simply uses the same reference to the object and will not copy it.